# How to fix blurry fonts on external monitor (M1 Mac Mini)

Tags: display, font

I previously had a HP U28 28" 4k monitor hooked up to it which worked fine. Now I've changed to a LG 32GN600-B 31.5" 2k 165Hz screen due to me also gaming on it with my Windows machine and when running 2k the fonts look so atrociously blurry that it gives me a headache within minutes. What can I do about it?

Comment: Sounds like a resolution mismatch which will cause the antialiasing algorithm to behave as you describe.   Are you certain you run the native resolution?

Comment: I am. 1080p (hidpi) looks about the same although there it's more like text seems to have a shadow instead of it looking blurry. From what I've read it's an antialiasing issue. Unfortunately as it its I won't be able to use this display with my mac. When I was using my U28 I had it scaled down to 1080p which was just right. Here the native resolution looks like hot garbage.

Comment: Which Update frequency do you use? You might be pushing the graphics card.

Comment: When running 1440p it's 144Hz, when running 1080p (hi-dpi) 60Hz is max. I'm going with the latter now. It's slightly better on the eyes. Nowhere near as good as what 1440p looks like on Windows though.

Answer (score 8):

I only but recently learned about [BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay). It actually solved all of my issues, though some limitations exists. Check it out!

Comment: This is a great tool so thanks for sharing!

Comment: I dont think it can resolve issue of having low ppi in monitor. Getting a 157 ppi monitor or up is the only solution.

Comment: so far turning on hiDPI using this tool was the only fix I found on my 1600x1200 displays.   thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to access 'hi-dpi' resolutions either by holding Alt while clicking on "Scaled" in the Display System preference, or checking the "Show all resolutions" box.

[image]

However, your 4K monitor at 28" has a pixel density of 157 ppi, whereas a 2K monitor at 31.5" has a pixel density of 93 ppi -- that's quite low, so slightly blurry text may be inevitable.

Comment: 1080p hidpi looks slightly better but still not good. When I was using my U28 I had it scaled down to 1080p which was just right. Here the native resolution looks like hot garbage.

Comment: @H3R3T1K Bigger monitors aren't always better.

Comment: I know. It's a tradeoff bc my gaming use under Windows. I would need a new screen AND gpu if I was to look for something that is great for both office use on Mac Mini and gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I was able to solve this by turning on "High Dynamic Range" for a Samsung external monitor on my Mac M1 Air.

[image: Display settings]

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/358596/how-to-fix-blurry-fonts-on-macos-mojave-with-subpixel-antialiasing/) guide which helped. Run

```
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
```

to re-enable subpixel antialiasing.

Comment: I have that value set, but I'm not convinced it does anything.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone come across this install [easyres](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/easyres/id688211836?mt=12)

and enable font smoothing `defaults -currentHost write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 0`
The "0" disables font smoothing, while "1" enables light font smoothing, "2" enables default medium smoothing, and "3" enables strong smoothing. For example, if after disabling font smoothing you want to return to the default setting, replace the "0" at the end of the command with a "2."